# Element id by javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using document.getElementsByTagName("input") to  get all the input elements in my form.While iterating through them I need to find an element with a particular id say "data" and process it.How can search in the elements such that an element of a particular id exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's some reason you don't want to do:

```
var el = document.getElementById('data');
```

...you could iterate over the collection:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), 
    len = inputs.length,
    el;

while( len-- ) {
    if( inputs[ len ].id === 'data' ) {  // Test the "id" property.
        el = inputs[ len ];              // If a match, grab that one,
        break;                           //     and break the loop.
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Fixed error where I had `el = inputs[ len ].id;` instead of `el = inputs[ len ];`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
document.getElementById("data")
```

Cause id's are unique.

Comment: yes i can do that , but when submitting a form  am submitting all the input elements so just have to select that one.

Comment: please check the above answer. That's what i wanted.